# How to subcribe an event of ALSpeechRecognition Naoqi in Python

Tags: python, nao-robot

Hi I want subcribe Event: "SpeechDetected" of ALSpeechRecognition API naoqi for Nao in python. Anyone know how to use this ??
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/audio/alspeechrecognition-api.html#SpeechDetected

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to create a python NAOqi module, 
then register to the variable using subscribeToEvent (or subscribeToMicroEvent).

you can have a look there: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/core/almemory-tuto.html#almemory-tuto

Beware: due to scoping the python variable must have the same name than the module name you create, as seen in this line:

```
pythonModule = myModule("pythonModule")
```

Comment: Thank for your comment I will try to